# Node + Angular2 App to Heroku Deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, angular2-routing

Facing Problem While deploying node app on heroku.

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch.

Source code : [Click Here!](https://github.com/arpitx165/Test-Website)

Node(version:v7.2.0) and npm (version:4.0.3)

[Error Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2daAJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check this : [Browser Sync Issue.](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1254)

Comment: I tried this one but its not working.Same issue I am facing again